# android facebook login for all user

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am new to Android and I created app which has Facebook login on it. During development time I have created facebook app and also created hash key. Everything works fine but what hash key should I put there (in facebook application) and upload to Google Play that every user can login via facebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias android-release -keystore app-release.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

You have to replace "android-release" with the name of the alias you used to sign the Market version of the app and replace "app-release.keystore" with the name/path of the appropriate (not debug) keystore.